# Update scripts not working as expected?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I need to update STATUS='R' for a given value of X, MONTH and YEAR
and STATUS='C' for everything before it upto the previous year.

(I am using variables instead of hard-coded values for X,MONTH and YEAR,below statments are just an example of what i am trying)

```
update A set STATUS = 'R' 
where X =1 
and MONTH = 7
and YEAR = 2011;

update A set STATUS = 'C' 
where X = 1
and MONTH < 7
and  YEAR <= 2011 
and  YEAR >= 2011 -  1;
```

Output comes like (**wrong output**):

```
....X   YEAR   MONTH   STATUS
....1   2010    1       C 
....1   2010    2       C 
....1   2010    3       C 
....1   2010    4       C 
....1   2010    5       C 
....1   2010    6       C 
....1   2010    7       R  //Actually this shoud be updated to C
....1   2010    8       R  //Actually this shoud be updated to C
....1   2010    9       R  //Actually this shoud be updated to C
....1   2010   10       R  //Actually this shoud be updated to C
....1   2010   11       R  //Actually this shoud be updated to C
....1   2010   12       R  //Actually this shoud be updated to C
....1   2011    1       C 
....1   2011    2       C 
....1   2011    3       C 
....1   2011    4       C 
....1   2011    5       C 
....1   2011    6       C 
....1   2011    7       R
```

Now the first update query works fine as we can see above.
now i am expecting to change everything above to STATUS='C'
but it doesn't gets applied to months 7 to 12 for year 2010.

please suggest.
`Oracle 9i Enterprise Edition release 9.2.8.0 - 64 bit Production`

Answer (score 0):

In your second update you set it for only MONTH < 7, so where its greater it doesn't do anything

Comment: yes i understand but i am very new to this....just learning...not sure how to make it up/update...also may be all of this could be done using single update statement

Comment: so if you don't want it for months less than 7, remove that part of the where clause

Comment: if i reamove it the R status(forthe row changed by the first query) will be changed back to C

Answer (score 0):

```
update A set STATUS = 'R' 
where X =1 
and MONTH = 7
and YEAR = 2011;

update A set STATUS = 'C' 
where X = 1
and YEAR = 2011 
and MONTH < 7

update A set STATUS = 'C' 
where X = 1  
and  YEAR = 2011 -  1;
```

this works